# C# ASP.NET - Add items to Combo Box (Ext.Net 2.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a FormPanel which has a couple of fields, however I've trouble adding items to the Combo Box (or a DropDown menu).

The question is then, how I can add values to a Combo Box or DropDown Menu?
Leaving the example code below:

```
 FormPanel win = new FormPanel()
        {
            ID = "Form",
            Title = "Example Form",
            Width = Unit.Pixel(500),
            Region = Ext.Net.Region.North,
            AutoRender = true,
            BodyPadding = 5,
            Items =
                {
                    new ItemCollection
                    {
                        new ComboBox
                        {
                            ID = "Dropdown",
                            FieldLabel = "Select one:",
                            AllowBlank = false,
                            Width = Unit.Pixel(420),
                        },
                    }
                },
        };
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the one for a comboBox:

```
ComboBox() comboBox1 = new ComboBox();    
comboBox1.Items.Add("StaffId");
comboBox1.Items.Add("Leave Type");
comboBox1.Items.Add("Start Date");
comboBox1.Items.Add("End Date");
comboBox1.Items.Add("Leave Status");
```

Comment: I currently re-wrote temporally to make it from the client side meanwhile, but I used a combo box instead I believe. Still, once the project is finished I will need to do it server side.

Comment: I have edited my answer to the one for combo box. Check if it meets what you want.@EricWeichhart

Comment: Sadly it didn't work as I can't give a variable to the Combo Box **but** this can be used to add after the element was created, which is a valid workaround.

Comment: So this will work for now. In the case I can find the way to add the items on the original code, I will update it.Thanks!